# Object property sibling access

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm making a game with a debugging console. It is structured like:

```
class Game
{
    bool debugMode;
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<Loop> loop;
    std::unique_ptr<Debugger> debugger;
    // ...
}
```

It works great in the class functions:

```
void Game::init()
{
    // ...
    loop = std::make_unique<Loop>();

    if (debugMode)
    {
        debugger = std::make_unique<Debugger>();
        debugger->console->write(L"Game initialized."); // works great!
    }
}
```

But what if I want to write something to the console in `loop`?

- I don't want to pass `debugger` to `loop`.
- I don't want to create
  another `debugger` in `loop`.

**How do I give `loop` access to `debugger`?**

Comment: That't easy. Just redesign your code to use `std::shared_ptr`, that both `Game` and `Loop` use. That's what `std::shared_ptr` is for.

Comment: Well... You kinda don't want the only reasonable options you have. You should use "dependency injection" and [parameters in make_unique()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I got it working with your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) as suggested by Sam Varshavchik.**

> Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object.<sup>[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)</sup>

This is now I got it to work, in case your interested:

```
class Game
{
    bool debugMode;
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<Loop> loop;
    std::shared_ptr<Debugger> debugger;
    // ...
}
```

The `init` function:

```
void Game::init()
{
    // ...

    if (debugMode)
    {
        debugger = std::make_unique<Debugger>();
        loop = std::make_unique<Loop>(debugger);
        debugger->console->write(L"Game initialized."); // works great!
    }
    else
    {
        loop = std::make_unique<Loop>();
    }
}
```

The `Loop` constructor:

```
Loop::Loop(std::shared_ptr<Debugger> debugger) : Loop()
{
    this->debugger = debugger;
}
```